# How to separate text in a column to many columns in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with values in 
10:10000018:SNP,a,g,0.5238,-0.0114,0.0268,0.6693,48969,46.6 format in 1 column. 
How do I separate the commas into separate columns in Notepad++? 
P.S. I don't know why but TextFX is not available in the plugin options.
Is there any other option available apart from Notepad++?

Comment: What is a column for you? [Edit your question](https://superuser.com/q/1467697/763386) and add some input lines and expected result.

Comment: So, my input line is like 10:10000018:SNP,a,g,0.5238,-0.0114,0.0268,0.6693,48969,46.6 and I would like my expected result to be like "10:10000018:SNP" in 1st cloumn, "a" in 2nd column, "g" in 3rd column and so on.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What is a column for you? What separator between columns? Do you want double quotes arround "column"? As I said above, **[Edit your question](https://superuser.com/q/1467697/763386)** and add some input lines and expected result **formatted**.